# Is there a form of energy corresponding to non-conservative forces?

Tags: energy

Potential energy is energy of conservative forces, so is there a type of energy corresponding to non-conservative forces (like friction) or not.

Answer (score 1):

For non-conservative forces, it's often impossible to track all the energy in the system. Look at the example of friction - some of the energy is lost due to particles of the two surfaces interacting with each other. This amount of energy is mostly converted to what you would macroscopically call thermal energy (movement of microscopical molecules). Some of the energy is also spent to create sound, etc. etc. Tracking all this changes is practically impossible.

Moreover, in case of friction, the surfaces get worn out (in practically unpredictable manner) as you rub them against each other. This makes friction unsuitable for a decent formalism like the one with conservative forces.

So, summing it up - in general, we don't have any analogue of potential energy for non-conservative forces. Perhaps there are some very very specific examples in which introducing something like that is possible, though I have not heard of any such example in my life, and I am very sceptical that something like that exist. As far as I know, physicists usually leave problems of non-conservative forces to engineers - they surely have some ways of coping with those forces but I do not know if they are in any way similar to potential energy etc.

Comment: To engineers the loss of energy is a design problem: it has to be removed from the system, usually in form of heat, or else it will damage it. There is an entire engineering discipline devoted to cooling. There are more complicated cases, e.g. when excess energy mechanically deforms and damages parts of the machinery. That is very important in the design of machine tools, for instance. So, yes, engineers are dealing with lost energy all the time, but they use the same physical laws.

Answer (score 1):

If you've formulated a problem using a non-conservative force, you've chosen to ignore some part of the energy involved. Energy is energy: arbitrary classifications of it may not apply. For friction, the lost energy is heat, but in statistical mechanics, heat is a combination of potential and kinetic energy, so the classification depends on how you want to treat it.

In a betatron, electrons gain energy from a nonconservative electric field. The energy budget is balanced by electrical energy from the power supply that energizes the magnet.